# Is the chat feature of ctrl-k documented anywhere besides the button onhover?

Tags: feature-request, chat

I don't see it anywhere, so can we make a request to add that to the chat-server FAQ where the other highlighting is?

If we're going to mention that, we should mention that it works on either occasion: pressing shift enter while typing (creates a new line, exposes that button), and pasting multiline text (which the javascript interprets as tho shift enter were pressed, as it produces identical results in that regard).

For reference what that does, consider the following chunk of XML (that I was conveniently just discussing in chat before this edit was made):

```
<do_command>
  <items>
    <create_new_type_of_event>
      <message type="string">Hello World</message>
    </create_new_type_of_event>
    <create_message_event>
      <message type="string">Hello World Again</message>
    </create_message_event>
  </items>
</do_command>
```

Notice how it is left aligned with the column (the indentation was my own and came before the pressing of ctrl-k). Now watch what happens when I press ctrl-k:

```
    <do_command>
      <items>
        <create_new_type_of_event>
          <message type="string">Hello World</message>
        </create_new_type_of_event>
        <create_message_event>
          <message type="string">Hello World Again</message>
        </create_message_event>
      </items>
    </do_command>
```

And when I press it again:

```
<do_command>
  <items>
    <create_new_type_of_event>
      <message type="string">Hello World</message>
    </create_new_type_of_event>
    <create_message_event>
      <message type="string">Hello World Again</message>
    </create_message_event>
  </items>
</do_command>
```

And for clarification, it indents or un-indents the code by four spaces, whichever is appropriate. That same shortcut works in the WMD (I think it's still called that) editor on these pages, when adding a new post on any StackExchange site.

Comment: What does Ctrl-K do in chat?

Comment: I shall edit my question

Comment: If you acknowledge that the multi-line message functionality exists, how will [balpha's wish](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=140357#140357) ever come true?

Comment: Hmm. Is the *WMD feature* of Ctrl-K documented anywhere but the button onhover? (Honest question. I don't think it is, but I'm not 100% sure.)

Comment: @balpha I wasn't able to find it in the help anywhere (or mention of any other keyboard shortcuts, for that matter).

Comment: @balpha so what we need to do is extend the [meta-tag:feature-request] either by additional independent requests or making this one HUGE request to have those things documented?